# ofstream::open creates file, but then crashes (bad pointer in locale::getloc()?)

Tags: c++, file, crash, ofstream

So I have some code that looks like this, written in and compiled with Visual Studio 2010:

```
if ( outputFile.is_open() )
{
    outputFile.close();
}
if ( !outputFile.is_open() ) // condition for sanity-checking
{
    outputFile.open("errorOut.txt", ios::out);
}
```

This crashes on an access violation. Attaching a debugger shows that the first condition is false (`outputFile` is not open), the second condition is true (`outputFile` is closed, which is good since I just checked it). Then `open()` gets called, and eventually `locale::getloc()` attempts to dereference a null pointer, but I have no idea why that would be happening (since that's now three classes deep into the Standard Library).

Interestingly, the file "errorOut.txt" *does* get created, even though the `open` call crashes.

I've spent a few hours watching this in a debugger, but I honestly have no idea what's going on. Anyone have any ideas for even trying to determine what's wrong with the code? It's entirely possible that some code elsewhere is contributing to this situation (inherited code), but there's a lot of it and I don't even know where to look. Everything up to that point seems fine.

Comment: What compiler/platform? Seems fine http://ideone.com/HpEfV

Comment: Have you tried running it under a tool such as Valgrind to look for memory stomping errors in your code?

Comment: @hmjd: Visual Studio 2010; will edit that in (feel dumb for forgetting it). More importantly, this construction does not seem to cause the problem -- identical or similar code elsewhere (though with different ofstreams) has no problem. That's why I'm hoping someone who knows more about the inner details of `ofstream::open()` comes along and might now where else to look.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: Never heard of Valgrind, I'll look into that.

Comment: _Where_ is the code?  I've had problems with some implementations when using `std::locale` in the constructors of static objects; at least one implementation (stlport) doesn't ensure that it's constructed before first use.

Comment: @JamesKanze: If I understand your question, it's just in a (non-static) class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm not really sure if this is the best way to handle this, but since this involved some truly strange behavior (crashing in the middle of an STL function, and some other oddities like hanging on `exit(1);` and the like), I'll leave an explanation here for the future.

In our case, the error seemed to derive from some memory corruption going on in some truly awful code that we inherited. Cleaning up the code in general eliminated this crash and other strange behaviors displayed by the program.

I don't know if this will be useful to anyone; maybe it would have been better to simply delete the question. I'm actually somewhat curious if I should have, if anyone wants to leave a comment.