# Segfault while closing a ofstream in C++

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

I have a function `CloseLogFile` that gets called to close a log file after the logger has written 10000 lines to it. I have the lines to be logged stored in a `deque` of type `std::string`. Here is the header

```
#pragma once

#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_LINES 1000
#define MESSAGES_PER_WRITE 100

class AtlLogger
{
friend class Driver;
friend class OrderManagementSystem;

public:
    static AtlLogger* Instance();

    void Log(const std::string line, const std::string prefix);
    void DeleteInstance();

    void WriteToFile();
private:
    AtlLogger();

    //the pointer versions of logging is reserved for internal use
    //we don't want a strategy to log with pointers and deal with
    //memory management
    void Log(const std::string*);
    void Log(const std::string*, std::string prefix);

    struct LogRequest
    {
        const std::string* line;
        std::string prefix;
    };

    struct FileInfo
    {
        std::string* name;
        std::ofstream ofs;
        int lines;
    };

    static AtlLogger* instance;

    void OpenLogFile(const std::string&);
    void CloseLogFile(const std::string&);

    bool run;

    std::deque<LogRequest*> message_queue;
    std::map<std::string, FileInfo*> file_map;
};
```

Here is the .cpp file:

```
#include "AtlLogger.h"

AtlLogger* AtlLogger::instance = NULL;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

/*
* @construct
* @param
* @description  creates a logger to record system information
*/
AtlLogger::AtlLogger()
{
std::string prefix("Audit");
OpenLogFile(prefix);
run = true;
}

/*
* @return instance: pointer to singleton class
* @description  creates an instance of the singleton
*       if it does not already exist
*/
AtlLogger* AtlLogger::Instance()
{
if(instance == NULL)
{
    instance = new AtlLogger;
}

return instance;
}

/*
* @param
* @return
* @description  deletes the logger after closing all IO
*/
void AtlLogger::DeleteInstance()
{
usleep(100000);
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
run = false;
std::map<std::string, FileInfo* >::iterator it;
for (it = file_map.begin(); it != file_map.end(); it++)
{
    //TODO ofstream* file = (*file_it).second;
    //file->close();
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

delete instance;
instance = NULL;
}

/*
* @param line:  string to be logged
* @return
* @description  adds a line to the queue of lines that 
*       will be written to the log
*/
void AtlLogger::Log(const std::string* line)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    LogRequest* request = new LogRequest;
    request->line = line;
    request->prefix = "Audit";
    message_queue.push_back(request);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

/*
* @param line:  string to be logged
* @param name:  name of the file to log with
* @return
* @description  add the line to the given log file
*/
void AtlLogger::Log(const std::string* line, std::string prefix)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (file_map.find(prefix) == file_map.end())
    {
        OpenLogFile(prefix);
    }

    LogRequest* request = new LogRequest;
    request->line = line;
    request->prefix = prefix;
    message_queue.push_back(request);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

/*
* @param line:  string to be logged
* @param name:  name of the file to log with
* @return
* @description  add the line to the given log file
*/
void AtlLogger::Log(const std::string line, std::string prefix)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (file_map.find(prefix) == file_map.end())
    {
        OpenLogFile(prefix);
    }

    LogRequest* request = new LogRequest;
    request->line = new std::string(line);
    request->prefix = prefix;
    message_queue.push_back(request);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

/*
* @param
* @return
* @description  runs in its own thread, checking whether it needs
*       to write log statements periodically
*/
void AtlLogger::WriteToFile()
{
    std::map<std::string, FileInfo* >::iterator it;

while(run)
{
    char timestamp[16];
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    struct tm* current = localtime(&now);
    sprintf(timestamp, "%02u%02u%04u|%02u%02u%02u|", (current->tm_mon+1),
        current->tm_mday,(1900 + current->tm_year), current->tm_hour,
        current->tm_min, current->tm_sec);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        for(it=file_map.begin(); it != file_map.end(); ++it)
        {
            if(it->second->lines > MAX_LINES)
            {
                CloseLogFile(it->first);
                OpenLogFile(it->first);
            }
            else
            {
                int written = 0;

                while(!message_queue.empty() && written < MESSAGES_PER_WRITE)
                {
                    LogRequest* request = message_queue.front();
                    message_queue.pop_front();

                    std::string line(timestamp, 16);
                    line.append(*(request->line));

                    FileInfo* info = file_map[request->prefix];
                    info->ofs << line << std::endl;
                    info->lines++;
                    written++;
                    delete request;
                }
            }
        }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    usleep(1000);
}
}

/*
* @param
* @return
* @description  opens a new file for logging with a timestamp
*       as the filename
*/
void AtlLogger::OpenLogFile(const std::string& prefix)
{
//get timestamp to use
char timestamp[15];
time_t now;
time(&now);
struct tm* current = localtime(&now);
sprintf(timestamp, "%02u%02u%04u_%02u%02u%02u", (current->tm_mon+1),
    current->tm_mday,(1900 + current->tm_year), current->tm_hour,
    current->tm_min, current->tm_sec);

FileInfo* info = new FileInfo;
cout << "1" << endl;
cout << prefix << endl;
info->name = new std::string("logs/" + prefix + ".log_" + timestamp);
cout << "2" << endl;
cout << "3" << endl;
cout << info->name->c_str() << endl;
info->ofs.open(info->name->c_str());
cout << "4" << endl;
info->lines = 0;
cout << "5" << endl;

file_map[prefix] = info;

cout << "Creating New Log File: " << timestamp << endl;
}

/*
* @param
* @return
* @description  closes the current log file
*/
void AtlLogger::CloseLogFile(const std::string& prefix)
{
cout << "Attempting to Close File!" << endl;
cout << prefix << endl;
cout << "Is Open?: " << file_map[prefix]->ofs.is_open() << endl;
cout << "good?: " << file_map[prefix]->ofs.good() << endl;
cout << "eof?: " << file_map[prefix]->ofs.eof() << endl;
cout << "fail?: " << file_map[prefix]->ofs.fail() << endl;
cout << "bad?: " << file_map[prefix]->ofs.bad() << endl;
cout << "name? " << *file_map[prefix]->name << endl;
cout << "lines? " << file_map[prefix]->lines << endl;
//cout << "rdbuf: " << file_map[prefix]->ofs.rdbuf() << endl;
cout << "rdbuf open?: " << file_map[prefix]->ofs.rdbuf()->is_open() << endl;
file_map[prefix]->ofs.close();
cout << "closed stream" << endl;
delete file_map[prefix];
cout << "deleted memory" << endl;
file_map.erase(prefix);
cout << "Close File End!"<< endl;
}
```

Occasionally, my program seg faults and I can't seem to determine why that is. It works many times, and eventually seg faults, sometimes on the first call, sometimes many calls later.

Here is my backtrace from gdb:

```
0  0x0000003d8786d1b3 in _IO_un_link_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1  0x0000003d87860da7 in fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
2  0x000000336febb968 in std::__basic_file<char>::close() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
3  0x000000336fe69c17 in std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::close() () 
from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
4  0x000000336fe69cad in std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::close() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
5  0x00000000004c2a25 in AtlLogger::CloseLogFile() ()
6  0x00000000004c2ef1 in AtlLogger::WriteToFile() ()
7  0x0000000000482270 in Driver::launchLog (this=0x7fffffffe86f) at driver.cpp:672
8  0x000000000048228f in launchLogThread (ptr=0x7fffffffe86f) at driver.cpp:654
9  0x0000003d8840673d in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
10 0x0000003d878d3d1d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Here is the console output right before the seg fault:

```
Attempting to Close File!
test
Is Open?: 1
good?: 1
eof?: 0
fail?: 0
bad?: 0
name? logs/test.log_09132012_095549
lines? 1001
rdbuf open?: 1
```

Can anyone show me where this might be going wrong? (And on a side note, why in gdb I see line numbers for some parts of the trace, and not for others?)

The logging function can be used with the following:
`Logger::Instance()->Log("Log This", "File");`

Comment: It may be completely unrelated to your question, but in [my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526054/ofstreamopen-creates-file-but-then-crashes-bad-pointer-in-localegetloc), it turned out to be caused by memory corruption elsewhere in the program (we'd inherited some awful code). If nothing else works, you might want to try cleaning up the program in general if you can.

Comment: [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) is your friend. You have a bug somewhere else in your program, valgrind will find it for you. Alternatively, try reducing your program to the smallest possible program that still faults, a la http://sscce.org/.

Comment: What is `files["default"]`?  I have not seen that before.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong straight away so I'm leaving towards KRyans answer, memory corruption. valgrind is what you want.

Comment: @wallyk it is just a std::map<std::string, std::ofstream* >

Comment: @Robᵩ hmmm ok, I will look into valgrind, I have used it before, only sparingly. I will try to read up on it some more

Comment: @Joshua:  What does it map to?  It is something which is okay to close?

Comment: @wallyk It maps to a std::ofstream

Comment: Is it possible that you are calling `->close()` on an already-closed file? Is it possible that you are calling `->close()` on an already `delete`d file pointer?

Comment: @Joshua:  Yes, of course it closes a `std::ofstream`!  But which one?!

Comment: @Robᵩ It is not closed as indicated in my question. But how would I check if the file pointer is closed? I edited my question to display the code which creates the file

Comment: @wallyk I have edited my initial question, is that explain your question? Otherwise I am not sure what you mean

Answer (score 2):

This is a curious and unusual architecture.

There is (apparently) a global variable `files[]` containing a pre-opened file.

`CloseLogFile()` uses `files["default"]` and then closes it.  What happens if `CloseLogFile()` is closed again?  The function does not check for it already being closed.  And if other logic accesses `files["default"]`, will it check for it being open before assuming that it is open?

It would be more "normal" (architected as most programmers expect) to either make the log file an object which is self-contained—that is, does not depend on non-member functions to close it—or making the contents of the array not pointers, but the objects pointed to so that deleting the array causes automatic cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace looks like you're logging in a thread. The condition you see might be a race condition of the ofstream* being either deleted or invalidated in the main thread by the time you enter the CloseLogFile() in your logger thread.

You might need to synchronize the (simultenous?)calls to CloseLogFile() and whatever clean up logic you have in the main thread.

If you post your main() code, i might be able to give you exact fix/suggestions

Comment: please post the code that shows the threading workflow... i.e. how you spin off the log thread, how you submit for logging etc.